# How to design queue system?

Tags: database-design

I would like to implement queue manage system for my app. An user can be able to book a doctor.

this my flow

When a patient request a consultation, her/his request is in queue.

This the flow

The user send request an appointment, the system added is request in the list.
The system will notify the fist doctor who is connected in system
if the doctor accepted the request. The status is changed for "accepted"
if the doctor doesn't accepted the request. The system send a notification to the next nurse in the list.

**The database is Postgres
The notifications will be done with ActionCable  ( Web ) and push apple notificatopn**

The tables

```
Requests

id
profile_id
status
created_at
updated_at

Notifications
id
kind
user_id
created_at

Consultations
id
user_id
doctor_id
status ( inprogress/ done )
created_at
updated_at
```

i want do something simple for the moment but i would like your opinion on my flow and my tables

Comment: You could do it in the database, but there are also specialized message queuing systems such as RabbitMQ or MSMQ that may be simpler to integrate than rolling your own would be.

Comment: As an exercise -- why not; but if you do need a queue, use a queuing system.

Comment: do you know a exemple or tutorial how to implement a queu system with RabbitMQ ?